# pkgutil.ImpImporter not found installing pyaudio on Python 3.12

Tags: python

I tried to build an AI program which I followed a video on youtube but I got error.
When I try to "pip install pyaudio" and then I got that error.
I have got that "pip install numpy" and " pip install wheel" but that things weren't fix my troubles.

> pip version: 23.2.1
> python version: 3.12.0

```
C:\Users\admin!>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5_67tfiy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5_67tfiy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "C:\Users\admin!\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5_67tfiy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2191, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

How can I fix that troubles. Please help me. Thanks you all.

Comment: This library only supports Python 3.11 and older. ImpImporter has been deprecated since version 3.3 and was finally removed in Python 3.12. I'd suggest that the pyaudio bugtracker is the appropriate place to check whether this is being fixed and on what schedule.

Comment: That said -- is there a newer `pkg_resources` or a newer `setuptools` available? This might just be a place where you need to update pyaudio's transitive dependencies, not pyaudio itself.

Comment: Maybe you guys were right. I followed these steps from a video that was 3 years ago. I will try another tutorial.

Comment: Python 3.11 is still available to download, so you should be able to step back a version without much trouble.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean/77364602#77364602

Comment: PyAudio has been updated to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I just updated the virtualenv:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

After that create a new virtual environment using:

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3.12
```

Activate the virtual environment "venv" and it should be working and able to install your packages.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a virtualenv with `--reset-app-data` param.

This seems to have helped me, suggestion found at https://pythontest.com/posts/2023/2023-10-02-py312-impimporter/

The author also mentions `virtualenv --upgrade-embed-wheels`, I did that as well, not sure if that made a difference.