# AttributeError:module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'.Did you mean: 'zipimporter'? Getting requirement to build wheel did not run successfull

Tags: python, pycharm

what is this error and how to fix it?
i tried to do this [pkgutil.ImpImporter not found installing pyaudio on Python 3.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253684/pkgutil-impimporter-not-found-installing-pyaudio-on-python-3-12)
but it doesnt help me

so how can i fix that? please help

full error:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Temp\pip-build-env-flq4q4xi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "C:\Temp\pip-build-env-flq4q4xi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "C:\Temp\pip-build-env-flq4q4xi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2191, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

i installed wheel, i updated python to 3.12.0 , i updated pip